# what does this code mean,does, and how can i apply it

Tags: linux, perl, ubuntu, ssh

```
my($stdout, $stderr, $exit)
```

so i am trying to send command-lines to a remote server using a code but I don't know if i am doing it right, here is the code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use Net::SSH::Perl;
use strict;

#my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd("ls -l /home/$usr")
my $host = "$host";
my $usr = "$usr";
my $pwd = "$pwd";
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host);
$ssh->login($usr,$pwd);

$ssh->cmd("script /home/$usr/textput.txt/");
$ssh->cmd("ls -l /$usr/jrivas/");
$ssh->cmd("exit");
```

When i run the code it seems to work fine until i go check if it made the script in the server but it wasn't there so i am imagining is the way i am sending the commands.

UPDATE

I've managed to connect to my server and make the .txt file but i havent been able to automatically save it to my out pc instead of the server

here is my code so far

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Net::SSH2;
use Net::SSH::Expect;
use Net::SSH::Perl;
use Net::SSH;


#my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd("ls -l /home/$usr")
my $host = "host";
my $usr = "root";
my $pwd = "pwd";
#my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host);
#$ssh->login($usr,$pwd);
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new (
            host => "$host", 
            password=> "$pwd", 
            user => "$usr", 
            raw_pty => 1
   );
my $login_output = $ssh->login();
        if ($login_output !~ /Welcome/) {
            die "Login has failed. Login output was $login_output";
        }



my $script = $ssh->exec("script /home/jrivas/script_output.txt");
my $script = $ssh->exec("ls -l /home/jrivas");
my $script = $ssh->exec("ls -a /home/jrivas");
my($out, $err, $exit) = $ssh->cmd("cat script_output.txt");
my $script = $ssh->exec("exit");


#$ssh->cmd("script /home/jrivas/textputq.txt/");
#$ssh->cmd("ls -l /home/jrivas");
#$ssh->cmd("exit");
```

So next thing is to get the script_output.txt to save in my computer automatically

Thanks to @zdim for helping me :)

Comment: Did you try to run this code? If there were problems did you then try to solve them?  A legitimate question here is expected to be fairly specific and detailed, documenting what you tried and what happened, and how/why it didn't work.

Comment: @zdim i did run it, it seem to work fine but when i check the server i am connecting to the textput.txt wasn't there, and yes i am trying to solve it, that's exactly why i posted the question here, so what i think i am doing wrong is the way i send the commands to the server, thats why i need to know how to apply $stdout, $stderr, and $exit, is all part of the problem.

Comment: OK -- good that you added that information to the question. Then, do you expect `script ..` to make that file (did you try normally, from terminal)? Your code never asks for output, it just runs the commands.  Debugging: (1) **Check for errors**.  Does you program even gets to login? See modules docs. (2) Study the modules documentation.  It provides ways to retrieve what you want, it has methods for that.  Then check the error that it returns.  (This is if you did manage to log in in the first place.)

Comment: :) i just solved it i used a different module that had all i need it, thanks for the tips.

Comment: @zdim do you know if there is a way to save the SCRIPT in my pc instead of the server?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "_save the SCRIPT_" ?  Isn't that some program that you run?  Very good that you found the right tool!  (While I am pretty sure that this module can do it as well.)

Comment: @zdim yes the program runs the code, but basically what i am trying to achieve here is to send commands to the server and then saving the log that the script makes in my own pc, my program is only capable of only saving the log or script in the server.

Comment: I see.  Then you need to transfer the file from the server to your machine once the `script` completes.  One standard tool is `rsync`, another one `scp` (which you can nicely run out of a Perl program), but there are others as well.  On Windows there are yet other. Search for how to copy a file from a machine to another.

Comment: @zdim yeah that's what i wanted to do but the problem is that this is only that the server that we are actually going to do this on is ADP a big company where they have their on servers and a lot of restrictions we won't be able to transfer because we wouldn't be allowed to, so we are trying to find a way to save the script automatically in our on pc, we use to do it with Telnet because its much easier and is not encrypted so it made it easier to access other servers, but now we are force to do it with SSH which is very encrypted.

Comment: OK. So here is an idea.  The module has a way to return all output, `($out, $err, $exit) = $ssh->cmd($cmd);`, [see docs](http://search.cpan.org/~schwigon/Net-SSH-Perl-2.12/lib/Net/SSH/Perl.pm#%28$out,_$err,_$exit%29_=_$ssh-%3Ecmd%28$cmd,_[_$stdin_]%29).  So make the command print out the file itself, like `$cmd = "cat script";`.  If `script` is an ascii file then you'll get it back in the `$output`.  Check `$error`.  Check all errors.

Comment: In the future, all this should be **summarized in the question**. You would've had a number of good answers, instead of this thread of short comments.

Comment: Or `($out, $err, $exit) = $ssh->cmd("cat script_output.txt");` (after the script ran and made `output.txt` file), I am not sure what you need to transfer.

Comment: I see, i will try it. I will keep you updated. Thanks by the way i really appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome.  The most important part is now to see what should go into a question.  Anticipate questions in the mind of those who read it much like the ones I've asked in this exchange.  Provide enough detail, including a description of what you tried, complete with expected outcome and actual output.  Writing a good question and getting a bunch of good answers beats these crammed comments by a mile.

Comment: @zdim you are definitely right i will add more to the question, what i am trying to save in my computer automatically is the output.txt

Comment: @zdim i tried what you told me to but i am getting an error it says that "cmd" is not found in Net::SSH::Expect packets, although i am using both Net::SSH::Expect and Net::SSH::Perl.

Comment: According to your code, you are now using [Net::SSH:Expect](http://search.cpan.org/~bnegrao/Net-SSH-Expect-1.09/lib/Net/SSH/Expect.pod), which is a different module, and which indeed does not have a `cmd` method.  Please read documentation for modules you use.  I see that this one has `exec`, which should directly return the output.  So, try that. Then try again what I told you, but the module you were using before (`Net::SSH::Perl`).  As for the question, this one's done.  When you post in the future just be careful to post a _good_ question.

Comment: @zdim thank you man i finally got everything to work but theres another thing i need to know that you might know is there any way i can send an ENTER key through my own code using the cmd or anything like that?

Comment: That kind of functionality is what [Expect](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod) is about.  It allows you to interactively use the other program, receive its output and send it commands, like you work with (some) programs from the command line.  The link above is to Perl's module but `expect` is a time-honored Unix tool.  Then `Net::SSH::Expect` may be for that, too (but I don't know for fact).  Read the docs :)